# BackgroundWorker combined with ThreadPool or ParalellFor C# VS 2010

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, backgroundworker, parallel.foreach

I have a simple task which I want to achieve.

I am trying to encode multiple files using ffmpeg on command line using C#.

This is what I want to achieve.

Assume there are 'x' number of files in a list. And I want to run 'y' number of encoding processes simultaneously. After all files are encoded I am merging all x files. Encoding and merging part is done. Where I am stuck is the simultaneous working. I am familiar with backgroundworker, threadpooling, ParallelFor but all of these aren't giving me the result that I want. May be my approach is wrong. So I would appreciate if someone could help me how should I go about it and solve this problem using 1 technique or a combination of few.

P.S. While the files are encoding, I want to be able to update a progress bar on screen (Simple Form).
Obviously I would want the process to be as fast as possible.

Comment: You want to spawn multiple threads to encode multiple files, once all files finished you want to merge the new files together?

Comment: `all of these are giving me the result that I want`.  What result do you want and what are you getting now?  And can you post the code for what you've tried?

Comment: @Tsukasa yes that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783747(v=vs.110).aspx) with ParallelOptions as argument. That object has a property [MaxDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx) specifying the maximum number of concurrent tasks.

In the callback method You may increase a progress value that may be shown in GUI.

Comment: And make sure that you're increasing that progress value in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: @erikH the problem is that Parallel.ForEach stops the main UI thread because of which I am not able to update my progress bar.

Comment: Then look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8365346/386544)